# chnage a unix base timestamp column into time

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a column named `timestamp` in dataframe which extends for 30000 rows
I want to change the unit value of the column to time and date.

The first value is `1590000000000` and is going down with same or different values. I want to have the new df to have the timestamp depicted as time and date.

How do we do this this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method to convert the unix based timestamp to your required date-time format.
*Note: Here I am assuming that this timestamp is in **millisecond(ms)**.*

**Try this:**

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit="ms")
```

**Output:**

```
                timestamp
0 2020-05-20 18:40:00.000
...
...
```

Comment: yeap thats works. if i have another column lets say timestamp2 how can the above code formulated @shubham sharma

Comment: @redplanet can you explain little bit more?

Comment: i have this columns

activity, timestamp accx, accy, accz, timestamp1, gyrox, gyroy, gyro z

i want with your code the change the timestamp and timestamp1 column

Comment: @redplanet just use `df["timestamp1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp1"], unit="ms")`.

Comment: ok thanks i was wondering if i can do that in one line

because now i fisrt enter df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit="ms")

df.head()

and then df["timestamp1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp1"], unit="ms"

df.head()

Comment: you can use `df = df.assign(timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit="ms"), timestamp1=pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp1"], unit="ms"))`

Comment: yeah, that is wonderful thank you. If I want to synchronize the timestamps for every given time do you think that the resample method will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `pd.to_datetime(df['mydates']).apply(lambda x: x.date())`

Comment: yeah that change the timestamp to date and time of i change x.date to x.time but i am missing my original format in df which has 8 column

what i want is to make the change but keep the original df with the same columns

the only difference is that column timestamp will have the new valus